# Could not print special symbols/characters using alivePdf in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, alivepdf

I am using alivePdf for generating pdf in flex.
How can we print Delta (Δ) symbol using alive pdf in flex?
I could print °C, but Δ symbol is not working...